# Giving Clash of Clans account

Tags: clash-of-clans

I have a Clash of Clans account in my iPad. My friend has his Clash of Clans account in his Android smartphone. Now I want to give my account to him. But I don't want to link my account with his as this will erase his village. But I want a solution so that my friend can play his account and also my village both together. Please help.

Comment: Please do note that it may be possible that this procedure is illegal under Supercell's terms of usage.

Comment: Careful, it is a "violation of Supercell's Terms of Service" - this  does not make it "illegal" (i.e. criminal).  See for example [this article from the Electronic Freedom Foundation](https://www.eff.org/deeplinks/2010/07/court-violating-terms-service-not-crime-bypassing)

Answer (score 4):

Yes this is possible. What your friend is going to need are at least two Google accounts linked to his phone.

First, from within Clash of Clans, go into settings and connect the current village to a Google+ account. This will allow him to restore his village from any device that he signs into his Google account from.

Then in Android,go to settings -> Apps -> Clash of Clans, and 'Clear Data'. This will wipe the village off the device, but it will still be linked to the Google+ account.

Now open Clash of Clans again and get past the intro tutorial. On your iOS device, open Clash of Clans, go to Settings -> Link a Device -> This is the old device. On the Android phone, open Clash of Clans, go to settings -> Link a Device -> This is the new device. Follow the steps to link the Android phone to your village. Now connect the new village to a second Google+ account (Must be different than the first one!)

Now any time he wants to switch between the two, he just simply needs to Clear Data as explained above. After loading Clash of Clans, he will be able to sign into a Google+ account (there's now an option to do so without doing the tutorial), and restore its respective village.

I just tried this entire procedure and verified it works.

For future reference, [it appears that Android phones will soon be getting user profiles](http://m.techradar.com/news/software/operating-systems/good-news-parents-multiple-user-accounts-coming-to-android-phones-1260564). So that like Android tablets, different user profiles store different sets of user data. When this feature comes out, it would be possible to setup each village on a different user profile and just simply switch between the profiles, no clearing user data needed. Though I would always recommend linking each village to a Google+ account for safety.

Answer (score 2):

Donating your account to someone else is **not allowed** by the Clash of Clans [Terms of Service](http://supercell.com/en/terms-of-service/), which you have aggreed to upon installing the game, registering an account or playing the game or using their services in any other way.

From the ToS: Under 1.1

> You shall not sell, rent or give away your Account, create an Account using a false identity or information, or on behalf of someone other than yourself; You shall not use the Service if you have previously been removed by Supercell, or previously been banned from playing any Supercell game;.

a bit further:

> You shall not share the Account or the Login Information, nor let anyone else access your Account or do anything else that might jeopardize the security of your Account.

What can happen if you do it anyway?
In section 1.2 of the ToS:

> WITHOUT LIMITING ANY OTHER REMEDIES, SUPERCELL MAY LIMIT, SUSPEND, TERMINATE, MODIFY, OR DELETE ACCOUNTS OR ACCESS TO SUPERCELL SERVICES OR PORTIONS THEREOF IF YOU ARE, OR SUPERCELL SUSPECTS THAT YOU ARE, FAILING TO COMPLY WITH ANY OF THESE TERMS OF SERVICE OR FOR ANY ACTUAL OR SUSPECTED ILLEGAL OR IMPROPER USE OF THE SERVICE, WITH OR WITHOUT NOTICE TO YOU. YOU CAN LOSE YOUR USER NAME AND PERSONA AS A RESULT OF ACCOUNT TERMINATION OR LIMITATION, AS WELL AS ANY BENEFITS, PRIVILEGES, EARNED ITEMS AND PURCHASED ITEMS ASSOCIATED WITH YOUR USE OF THE SERVICE, AND SUPERCELL IS UNDER NO OBLIGATION TO COMPENSATE YOU FOR ANY SUCH LOSSES OR RESULTS.

But it is your account right? And you can do what you want with it right?
nope!

> 2.2. Accounts
>   NOTWITHSTANDING ANYTHING TO THE CONTRARY HEREIN, YOU ACKNOWLEDGE AND AGREE THAT YOU SHALL HAVE NO OWNERSHIP OR OTHER PROPERTY INTEREST IN THE ACCOUNT, AND YOU FURTHER ACKNOWLEDGE AND AGREE THAT ALL RIGHTS IN AND TO THE ACCOUNT ARE AND SHALL FOREVER BE OWNED BY AND INURE TO THE BENEFIT OF SUPERCELL.

The above are just small exerpts of the Terms of Service by Supercell. You can read the full ToS [here](http://supercell.com/en/terms-of-service/)

Personally, I don't recommend you giving your account to someone else.
It may result in the removal of both your account and the recipients already existing account.

Answer (score 1):

To remove Clash of Clans from your friend's account by following these steps:

1. Open your Android device, of course.
2. Open Google Settings.
3. Open Connected Apps then tap to Clash of Clans.
4. Tap to Disconnect to remove this game from your account.
5. Done.

Source: [Removing Clash of Clans from Google Account](http://cocland.com/tutorials/removing-clash-of-clans-from-google-account)

Then follow this tutorial to transfer your village from Android to iOS:

1. Open Clash of Clans on both your iOS and Android devices
2. On your Android device, you need to connect your village with
   Google+, and on your iOS device, you need to connect your village
   with the Game Center.
3. Open Settings Menu in Clash of Clans on both devices.
4. Tap to the ‘Link a device’ button.
5. Just follow the instructions on the screen.

Source:

Answer (score -1):

You can't do that. The only available thing is linking both of the accounts.

Account connectivity on Apple and Android are totally different.

Comment: Do you have a source for this information?